# What is the number next to the method name in a stack trace?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, stack-trace

I have a simple question, I suppose, but I cannot find anything.

What's the number at the end of line 6, `+ 429`?

[image: stack trace image]

Comment: If you're trying to debug this particular crash I can tell you that you're missing a reuse identifier for your cell in IB. I'm guessing you're using the new dynamic prototypes for UITableView construction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that the return address for stack frame 6 is 429 bytes past the start of the -[#### tableView:cellForRowAtindexPath:] function.  It might be inside that function, or it might be past the end of the function but not inside any other known function.

### UPDATE

In order for the symbolicator to turn those return addresses into line numbers, you must have the `.dSYM` file that the linker created when it created the executable file.  Each executable is tagged with a UUID, and the `.dSYM` file is tagged with the same UUID.  The symbolicator looks at the UUID of the executable and uses Spotlight (OS X's filesystem search support) to find the matching `.dSYM`.  If you didn't save the `.dSYM`, you will have a hard time turning the addresses into line numbers.  Note that when you tell Xcode to build an archive (Product > Archive), the archive contains both the executable and its matching `.dSYM`.

Comment: many thanks. i'm new in debugging xcode, only a little question, i'm learning about a useful new word: symbolication. But with the organizer -> device logs, could i find the exact line of crash??

Comment: Read Tech Note 2123. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html

Comment: thanks for the link, i have read the main content, but there are a lot of information. I tried also to run symbolicatecrash but with the crash show above i have the same result, nothing about the line of crash. I think the crash is simbolicated (right?) but miss the line number.
i have only one doubt: i don't have the submitted dSYM but i have the source code. Is possible to ricreate the dSYM and be able to find the line number? Only YES or NO, then i will try to find how. thanks